# Find user with specific value in employeeID attribute

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to find the CN of a username by searching for the employeeID attribute (which is unique for each employee). I already got it to return a string with all attributes, but I want it to return only the CN of a user (ex: 'John Doe' or 'cn=John Doe'; both are fine)

```
public void getEmployeeId(String id) {
        // TODO stuff
        String groupName = "ou=Accounts,DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE";

        try {
            System.out.println("Creating initial directory context...");
            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

            // Create default search controls
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();


            // Search for user with 'id' as value for employeeID attribute
            String filter = "(&(employeeID=" +id + "))";

            // Search for objects using filter
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(groupName, filter, ctls);

            // Print the answer
            // Search.printSearchEnumeration(answer);

            System.out.println("-----------------");
            System.out.println(answer.next());
            System.out.println("-----------------");

            // Close the context when we're done
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*note: I know you can just cut parts from a string, but I want it to return only the value I need.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search request should contain a list of attributes. Some APIs will return all attributes from matching entries. Specify `cn` in the list of attributes to return, and be prepared to handle a multi-valued `cn` attribute.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            /***/
            NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search(
                    "dc=stackoverflow,dc=com, "employeeID=" +id,
                    ctls);
            while (namingEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) namingEnum.next();
                Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
                System.out.println(attrs.get("cn"));
                System.out.println(attrs.get("name"));
                System.out.println(attrs.get("userPrincipalName"));
            }
            /***/
```

the result:

CN: Andres Montejo

NAME: Andres Montejo

userPrincipalName: andresmontejo@stackoverflow.com